# VS 2012: Debugger: "Break all in 5 seconds"

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2012

My program is using too much CPU power when I select text. And I don't know why. Normally I'd just press "Break all" to see what the program is currently doing. But in this case I'm busy selecting text with the mouse.

Is there any trick to delay the "Break all" command for a few seconds?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can start a separate thread with `Sleep(5000); DebugBreak();`

Answer (score 0):

Press CTRL-Break while selecting. This should bring the debugger up immediately.

Comment: But OP doesn't want to break while he's selecting text, he wants a delay.

Comment: Well, that was just an idea I guess. What he wants is being able to see the state of the application while selecting text and what method is eating CPU while he drags the mouse over the text.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I had forgotten the part of the question before the question by the time I got here.

Comment: Sounds good, but I couldn't get it to work. No reaction to Ctrl+Break when my app is in the foreground.

Comment: Checked it again. On my system it's Ctrl+Alt+Break (perhaps different shortcut layout). But that only works with VS in the foreground. Not while I'm selecting stuff (=click-drag) in my app.

Comment: Then that is really a stupid situation. In most cases like this, it also helps to make sure the VS window is not overlapping your App window, because this prevents most events that would otherwise be sent to your app (WM_REDRAW, etc). But in this particular case that wouldn't help either, I believe, because the focus is lost. The only idea that I have now is to use a second computer and remote debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You can sprinkle all your suspicious code with special kind of breakpoints that do not stop execution, but print a message in Output window.

Add a breakpoint, go to Breakpoints window, find the breakpoint that was just added, right-click, select "When Hit...", in new window select "Print a message". Make sure check box "Continue execution" is checked (it should be by default). Breakpoint icon will change from circle to diamond. Repeat this for several breakpoints.

You can adjust the text that breakpoint will display to whatever you need.